# Select unique names within a list removing duplicate entries

Tags: python, list

Is there a way I can highlight only the lines in a file that are not duplicated?
Taking as example the following file content:

```
Product 1
Product 1
Product 2
Product 3
Product 3
```

I want to be able to highlight `Product 2`, as its the only one without a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
from collections import Counter
with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
    count = Counter(f.read().split("\n"))
    print [x for x in count if count[x] == 1]
```

This will maintain a counter of all lines, with how many times each line occurs, from which you can filter out the ones you need later.

Answer (score 1):

One hacky way to do it is :

```
>>> with open('test.txt') as fp:
...     x = fp.readlines()
...     print([i for i in x if x.count(i) ==1])
```

This will check if the number of occurrences of each line is more than 1 and print only those which don't occur more than once.

Ref:

- [`count`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) function